# Есть проблемы при создании генерации случайного числа

Tags: javascript

Решил я сделать генератор случайных чисел, есть 2 input'а, куда пользователь вводит `min` и `max`, после нажимает на сгенерировать и ему выдается случайное число в диапазоне тех цифр, которые он ввёл. Так вот проблема в том, что нужно проверять, если пользователь ввёл одинаковые числа, то `max` нужно прибавлять на единицу, если пользователь ввёл, что `min` больше, чем `max`, то `max` нужно сделать таким же числом, как `min` и добавить единицу.
Вот то, что сделал я:

```js
let inp1 = document.querySelector('.inp1')
let inp2 = document.querySelector('.inp2')
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let out = document.querySelector('.out')

btn.addEventListener('click', randomNumber)

function randomNumber (min, max) {
    min = inp1.value;
    max = inp2.value;

    if (inp1.value == inp2.value) {
        inp2.value++
    } else if (inp1.value > inp2.value) {
        inp2.value = parseInt( inp1.value + 1)
    }

    out.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #141414;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.input {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.out {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="out">0</div>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="number" class="inp1">
          <input type="number" class="inp2">
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Сгенерировать</button>
      </div>
    

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в

```
inp1.value + 1
```

Так как `inp1.value` — строка, оператор `+` — это конкатенация строк.
Необходимо привести строку к числу.
Например:

```
inp2.value = parseInt(inp1.value, 10) + 1
```

Или:

```
inp2.value = +inp1.value + 1
```

---

Вторая проблема в ранней инициализации переменных min и max.
Это нужно делать после валидации и изменений значений в полях ввода.

---

Теперь взглянем на сравнение:

```
inp1.value > inp2.value
```

Мы сравниваем строки, они сравниваются **лексикографически**.
Т.е. `'2' > '19'`. Для корректного сравнения, нужно привести их к числам.

---

Так как, мы теперь пришли к слишком большому количеству преобразований, делаем шаг назад и вводим переменные с числами в самом начале, модифицируем их и кладём результаты преобразования обратно.

---

Ещё: `btn.addEventListener('click', randomNumber)` передаёт в randomNumber объект события. Нужно либо явно передать нужные вам аргументы
`btn.addEventListener('click', () => randomNumber(inp1.value, inp2.value))`
либо параметры в определении функции бесполезны(вам всё равно приходится ходить в поля ввода за данными)

---

Также, я добавил +1 к генерации числа, чтобы включать значение во втором поле.

```js
let inp1 = document.querySelector('.inp1')
let inp2 = document.querySelector('.inp2')
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let out = document.querySelector('.out')

btn.addEventListener('click', randomNumber)

function randomNumber() {
  let [min, max] = [+inp1.value, +inp2.value]; // Формируем числа
  if (min == max) { // Валидация, модификация
    max++
  } else if (min > max) {
    max = min + 1
  }
  [inp1.value, inp2.value] = [min, max] // Обновляем поля ввода

  out.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #141414;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.out {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="out">0</div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="number" class="inp1">
      <input type="number" class="inp2">
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Сгенерировать</button>
  </div>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а как исправить проблему, то что, если, min > max то равнять его с min и добавлять +1?

Comment: Понял о чём речь, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое)